# alwayson status

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

If  secondary replicas of databases are  continuously in synchronizing state ,what it means. We are using asyn mode with manual failover.

[image]

Comment: Voting to close since this could be solved with a quick search of the AlwaysOn documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The "Synchronizing" state means that it is actively synchronizing the data to the asynchronous replica. This is a healthy state for an asynchronous replica. When it is a synchronous replica, it will say "Synchronized" when it is up to date and "Synchronizing" when it is trying to catch up.

Check [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alwaysonpro/2014/11/11/determine-availability-group-synchronization-state-minimize-data-loss-when-quorum-is-forced/) out for more information on synchronization states.

Comment: Thanks..but all time it is in synchronizing state.is this healthy state?

Comment: Yes this is a healthy state. It will not ever say synchronized for an asynchronous replica. When you want to do a manual failover, switch it to a synchronous replica and then do the failover with no data loss.

Comment: @user2011956 - understand that "asynchronous" means the secondary is updated in a "best effort" way.  Databases in a "Synchronous" replica are guaranteed to have log records sent to the secondaries prior to the transaction being committed on the primary.  Perhaps you need "Synchronous" instead of "Asynchronous"?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, when you have AG running in Async state, below is what I would do when doing failover

- **Pre:** Change the Sync mode to "Synchronous"
- **Pre:** Check `master.sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states.is_failover_ready = 1` and then failover
- **post:** turn on async

From [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877957.aspx) :

> **is_failover_ready = 1,** the database is marked as synchronized in the cluster and is ready for a failover.
>                       If is_failover_ready = 1 on every database on a given secondary replica, 
>                       you can perform a forced failover (FORCE_FAILOVER_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) without data loss on this secondary replica.
>
> If **is_failover_ready = 0,** the database is not marked as synchronized in the cluster and is not ready for a planned manual failover. 
>                       If you force failover to the host secondary replica, data will be lost on this database.
>    */